# Phonegap scrolling issues on android 5

Tags: javascript, css, cordova, android-5.0-lollipop, phonegap-build

We are developing an app using Phonegap/Javascript.

Scrolling used to work fine, until we tried the new Android 5.
The page does not scroll down, unless you swipe many times. Then it is stuck in the other position..

Can't find anyone with this problem!
We are using just simple divs with content that is taller than the screen. Works fine on Android <5 or iOS.

Any ideas?

Comment: i suggest you to remove all the transition properties and go for the kill..i.e., no hardware acceleration

Comment: This is what we are already doing, no fancy stuff, no transitions, just simple html.. works fine anywhere else other than Android 5..

Comment: try this in Your mainactivity  view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);

Comment: I'm considering using some plugin like iScroll or Overthrow. Used iScroll a lot before, and was happy that it's not really needed with the current popular phones.. :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what finally solved the problem, along with simplifying properties, etc.:

Hammer.defaults.stop_browser_behavior.touchAction = 'pan-y';

It was an issue with the hammer.js plugin with touchAction property.
This affects some browsers - and apparently also Android 5 (but doesn't affect Android 4.* when using PhoneGap).

Not as simple as it seems, more details here:
https://github.com/hammerjs/hammer.js/wiki/How-to-fix-Chrome-35--and-IE10--scrolling-(touch-action)